# str_replace and preg_replace is not working

Tags: php

I have try to replace `-` by `<` but is not working.

```
$str = "JEAN-pierre, BRUNÔ";  
function replaceName($str){
    //$new_str1 = preg_replace('/-/', '<', $str);
    $new_str1 = str_replace("-", "<", $str);
    return $new_str1;
}
```

that return: `JEAN` not `JEAN<PIERRE, BRUNÔ`

Thanks you!

Comment: If the output is in a browser, the `<` is being taken as the start of a HTML tag.

Comment: works fine in any php ide. but as @NigelRen said it will acts with < as a tag not output

Comment: Take a look at the source or inspect element to see what actually gets output

Comment: You shouldn't use regex for this `str_replace` usage is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted is fine. The issue you're more than likely running into is that `<` will be treated as the start of a HTML tag, hence the rest of the value is hidden.

You need to escape your `<` character before displaying it on the page.

You could use `htmlspecialchars()` as part of the output:

```
echo htmlspecialchars( replaceName( 'NAME' ) );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php